# Can I use java generics to have different implementations of same interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I want to convert a class into another using generics. can I do that?

for eg.

```
Class BConvertImpl implements Converter
{
  A toA(Class B);
  void update(Class A, Class B);
}

Class CConverterImpl implements Converter
{
  A toA(Class C);
  void update(Class A, Class C);
}
```

Can I use generics to implement this?

I am pretty new to Generics in Java. can somebody help me with this one?

Thanks

Comment: I think you've got a typo in your second class "Comverter" where you intend "Converter". I'm not going to just change it because *maybe* it is intentional and relevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: You need to type your `Converter` class (and name the method simply `to`):

```
/**
 * @param <F> The "from" type
 * @param <T> The "to" type
 */
interface Converter<F, T> {

  T to(F from);

  void update(T to, F from);
}

class BConvertImpl implements Converter<B, A> {

  A to(B from) { /* some impl */ }

  void update(A to, B from) { /* some impl */ }
}

class CConverterImpl implements Converter<C, A> {

  A to(C from) { /* some impl */ }

  void update(A to, C from) { /* some impl */ }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as written. `F` and `T` are type parameters, not parameter names, so `to(Class F)` won't compile. You mean `to(F f)`.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Yikes! Thanks - fixed now (I just write code into here without using an IDE to check it - doh!).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
interface Converter<From, To> {
    public To convert(From object);
}

class BConverter implements Converter<B, A> {
    public A convert(B b) {
        ...
    }
}

class CConverter implements Converter<C, A> {
    public A convert(C c) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This lets you define the `Converter` interface in a generic way and then you can have whatever implementations you need.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. You cannot convert classes in Java like this or any other way. What you can do is create handlers that will accept any of a kind of `Converter`, which I suspect is more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: -1 I'm gonna have to downvote this one. There's no getting around it... this answer simply incorrect.